# Seg fault initializing vector of lists with input from console

Tags: c++, list, vector, graph, segmentation-fault

I've been working on a solution to a problem involving a tree. My strategy was to take the input and represent the graph as an adjacency list. Unfortunately I'm getting a segmentation fault and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */

    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int M; 
    cin >> M;

    // matrix of adjacency list to hold node values
    vector<list<int> > adjList(M, list<int>());

    // create adjacency list
    int ui, vi;
    while(true) {
      cin >> ui;
      cin >> vi;
      ui--;
      vi--;

      adjList[ui].push_front(vi);
      adjList[vi].push_back(ui);

    }

return 0;
}
```

When I run the program and type in this input it stops running with a segmentation fault.

```
10 9
2 1
3 1
4 3
5 2
6 1
7 2
8 6
9 8
10 8
```

Note: The first line is not part of the graph, it defines the constraints of the graph. So 10 vertices and 9 edges total for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector has `M=9` elements. These are numbered from 0 to 8, and your code is trying to access the element at index 9 (the 10 in the last line decremented by one).

Comment: Wow, I could've sworn I looked at that before posting. It works now thank you!